# KDevelop4: target build directory doubled after importing CMakeList.txt

Tags: c++, build, cmake, kdevelop

When I try to compile individual build targets from project imported via `CMakeList.txt` I get error saying that file cannot be found. The error message cite path which is doubled the true path:

[image]

the propper path should be:
`/u/25/prokoph1/unix/git/SimpleSimulationEngine/cpp/build`
(this is computer in university network which could mess path a bit)

**Background:** I'm have big CMake C++ project (https://github.com/ProkopHapala/SimpleSimulationEngine) with >100 nested build targets. Up to now I was using Code::Blocks generator, now I'm trying to Kdevelop4 which looks pretty cool. It is able to load `CMakeList.txt` without any project-generator. The code navigation (*Jump to declaration*) works very well. It can compile the whole project without any problem. But compilation and running individual build targets does not work.

Answer (score 1):

KDevelop 4 is unmaintained anymore.
You should use KDevelop 5.
If your distribution does not provide a fresh version, I suggest using the AppImage from https://www.kdevelop.org/download